# Reference request + What philosophies are there as to ontology of numbers?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, reference-request

I have interest in ontology of numbers. I know that the two main schools of thought regarding the metaphysical status of numbers are mathematical Platonism and mathematical Nominalism. But I wonder - What other schools of thought address the question of the ontology of Numbers?
And, where may I find concise but yet profound introduction to this subject?

Comment: check out husserl, just recently a book fell into my hand, that was mainly about the ontology of numbers. so, the difference between cardinal numbers, ordinal numbers. onfortunately I don't remember the title at the moment.

Comment: @AntonHarald, thank you for this direction; if you (or anyone else) get to remember the precise name of the relevant text of Husserl or of any other philosopher, it would be helpful.

Comment: I found the text now, however here it is in german: https://www.freidok.uni-freiburg.de/fedora/objects/freidok:6159/datastreams/FILE1/content  English wiki page about the book: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very good SEP entry that covers a lot of ground regarding the subject in a clear and informative manner: [Platonism in the Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/platonism-mathematics/). (It has 'Platonism' in the title but gives you a good idea about opposing views as well).

Comment: Thank you for this reference. It does indeed cover some ground of the subject. Nonetheless, am still looking for a philosophical review or introduction which focuses directly on ontology of numbers. Thank you again.

Comment: @L.M.Student Try Frege's 'The Foundations of Arithmetic'